# Is it possible to permanently change the colour of CMD from the command line?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, windows-7

In CMD, `color 0a` changes the background and foreground colour to black and light green respectively. `cmd /T:0a` does the same thing.

However, both of these commands apply only to the current command-line session, and the only way I know of to change these properties permanently is by right-clicking a command prompt and clicking on Defaults. [This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945527/modify-cmd-exe-properties-using-the-command-prompt) asks the same question, but the answers given either provide commands for other properties or involve non-command line solutions.

**So, is it possible to change these settings permanently from the command line?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run:

```
> reg query  "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /S
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
    CompletionChar    REG_DWORD    0x9
    DefaultColor    REG_DWORD    0x0
    EnableExtensions    REG_DWORD    0x1
    PathCompletionChar    REG_DWORD    0x9
    DelayedExpansion    REG_DWORD    0x0
```

You'll see that entry DefaultColor and and it does what you guess, so:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v DefaultColor /t REG_DWORD /d 0x0a /f
```

Will set the color to light green on black background for every new console for the current user as long not forced otherwise (by a starting link for example).
BTW: I prefer 1e for bright yellow on dark blue background.

---

Some console apps store changes made via the system menu/properties (font/font size/layout/colors) in sub-/keys of `"hkcu\console"`. So it's quite interesting to look through:

```
reg query "hkcu\console" /S | more
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun /t REG_SZ /d "color f1" /f
```

If you read the `cmd /?` help screen you will find this metod documented.

If you can control the the title of the window, you can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24905911/2861476) to fully customize your window

Answer (score 0):

there is no direct command to permanently change color of cmd but you can use Reg command and edit HKLM\Console\ strings or edit HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor strings
for example:

```
Reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun /t REG_SZ /d "color 0f" /f
```